# Request return wrong data

Tags: hibernate, ninjaframework

In a project that uses NinjaFrameWork we are having a problem when querying the data with successive or concurrent requests.

In some cases it is receiving some data, and in other cases it is receiving other data. It seems as if the frameWork cache is kicking in at times.

We insert data into the database through a request style:

```
@Transactional
public Result askCita(Context context, DataCitasAsk cita) {

    manager.getTransaction().begin();
    manager.persist(cita);
    manager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

And when we collect data from the database through a request like this; but it does not always return the same data. Sometimes it does not return the last data inserted.

```
@Transactional
public Result listCitas(Context context, DataCitasList cita) {

    if (cita == null) {
        return Results.json().render(false);
    }

    // La IP del cliente
    String ipClient = context.getRemoteAddr();

    EntityManager entityManager = provider.get();
    DbCitas db = DbCitas.getInstance();

    DataCitasListResult vUser = db.listCitas(entityManager, cita);

    return Results.json().render(vUser);
}

public DataCitasListResult listCitas(EntityManager manager,
        DataCitasList data) {
    String uCheck = Cita.QUERY_CLINIC_MONTH;

    Calendar calBefore = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calAfter = Calendar.getInstance();
    calAfter.set(Calendar.MONTH, calAfter.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);

    DatabaseController db = DatabaseController.getInstance(manager);
    Query q = db.getQuery(uCheck);
    q.setParameter("dateBegan", calBefore.getTime());
    q.setParameter("dateEnd", calAfter.getTime());
    q.setParameter("idClinic", data.getIdClinic());

    List<Cita> list = q.getResultList();

    DbVetData vData = DbVetData.getInstance();
    VetData clinic = vData.getClinicDb(manager, data.getIdClinic());

    DataCitasListResult rData = new DataCitasListResult();
    rData.setClinica(clinic);
    rData.setCitas(new ArrayList<DataCitasResultItem>());

    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return rData;
    }

    ArrayList<DataCitasResultItem> lCitas = new ArrayList<DataCitasResultItem>();
    for (Cita cita : list) {
        DataCitasResultItem nCita = new DataCitasResultItem();
        nCita.setAnswered(cita.getDateVet() != null ? true : false);
        nCita.setCreated(spf.format(cita.getCreated().getTime()));
        if (cita.getDateCita() != null) {
            nCita.setDateCita(spf.format(cita.getDateCita().getTime()));
        }
        if (cita.getDateVet() != null) {
            nCita.setDateVet(spf.format(cita.getDateVet().getTime()));
        }
        nCita.setId(cita.getId());
        nCita.setIdMascota(cita.getPet().getId());
        nCita.setNameMascota(cita.getPet().getName());
        nCita.setMotivo(cita.getMotive());
        nCita.setTipoCita(cita.getType().getId());

        //
        lCitas.add(nCita);
    }
    rData.setCitas(lCitas);

    return rData;
}
```

In the database if they appear; it seems little more than consultation, insertion.

I do not understand why.

PD: I include the Citas.class definition:

```
@Entity(name = "citas")
   @Table(name = "citas")
   public class Cita {
 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "created")
    private Timestamp created;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_mascota")
    private Pet pet;

    @Column(name = "date_cita")
    private Calendar dateCita;
    @Column(name = "date_vet")
    private Calendar dateVet;
    @Column(name = "motivo")
    private String motive;
    @Column(name = "sended")
    private long sended;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tipo_cita")
    private CitaType type;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_clinica")
    private VetData clinica;

    }
```

Comment: You say it's actually in the database, but not all the expected results are coming back from your  `public DataCitasListResult listCitas(...)` method?

Comment: In the database were all the data, but sometimes the code don´t return the last ones.

Comment: I include de Class definition. @NicholasSmith

Comment: Does your console show you the full SQL and parameters used in your query?  I'm wondering if your date range includes hours/minutes and that is excluding some of your records from returning?

Comment: This make no sense; i change calendar.month; if were this, the range be the same always, not in some random requests to the same year/month/day/hour. I think.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the problem here but mentioned because I've seen it before trying to query by date.  Where start date had a time set, for example 09:00, and the object was created at 07:00 on that day so it wasn't included in the result set.  So i always set the calendar like: `cal.set(startYear, startMonth, 1, 0, 0, 0);` to zero out the time portion.  `Calendar.getInstance()` initializes date and time fields to current date and time.

Comment: But if i want all the entries between now and next month; i need to setup Calendar with getInstance, nothing more. Or not?

Comment: Reading the last comments i think that you don´t understand me (or maybe i don´t explain myself as i thought). Example: With Calendar range (for ex. 25-07-2015 12:00 -> 25-08-2015 12:00 in dateCita); i got in database some data with this range; but the two last inserted was created in the last 5minutes. When i do query data to this range, sometimes the last ones (inserted) wasn´t show, but they must. I hope you understand my problem now, thankYou anyway.

Comment: If the objects in your database look right, and the sql `where` clause looks good, you could change your hibernate config to disable caching and see if that makes a difference?